# How to use ant to compile and deploy my webapp in openshift server?

Tags: openshift

I don't have ant in my server. When I do `rhc ssh myapp` and tried to use ant, it shows "bash: ant: command not found". But I find jars related to ant in my folder "jbossews/lib/catalina-ant.jar".
I tried to install ant by `sudo apt-get install ant`, but it shows "bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied"
so I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ant functionality is not available on OpenShift at this time. I'm working on clearing up some conflicting articles on our side. Also, *root access* (sudo) isn't available to users in their gears.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the commands below:

wget https://www.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.zip

unzip apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.zip