# Setting up Tomcat on DIY OpenShift app for use with Java8

Tags: tomcat, java-8, openshift

I'm trying to set up a DIY application on OpenShift which uses Java8 and Tomcat. I was going by [this tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-run-apache-tomcat-8-on-openshift/) to build tomcat 8 until I found that [ant is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592421/how-to-use-ant-to-compile-and-deploy-my-webapp-in-openshift-server) on OpenShift.

I wanted to use Tomcat8 to avoid any problems with Java8, but at that point I went back to try using Tomcat7. As I can't build it without ant I tried installing [this cartridge](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-tomcat-quickstart), which gave me the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/lib/openshift)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Is there another way to build Tomcat8, or use Tomcat7 on a DIY app? Or another way to use Java8 with Tomcat on OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me once (http://things-of-the-day.blogspot.com.ar/2015/08/instalar-tomcat-8-con-java-8-en.html), right now I'm trying to use it again, but the tomcat's url is broken. I'm looking for a new one.

**EDIT**

found it: http://mirrors.koehn.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.28/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.28.tar.gz

**EDIT**
One more thing. Use the openshift blog post you are using now, to configure the server.xml so your tomcat will use the correct ports.